# Function doesn't execute inside loop

Tags: haxe

I'm making a simple terminal calculator but for some reason a function isn't executing inside a while loop but executes outside the loop.

Given this input: `((1 + 2) + (3 + 4))`

It should output:`10`

But gets stuck in an infinite loop because it doesn't replace the innermost expressions with their result.

The function that doesn't execute is `s.replace(basicOp, answer);`

Here is a snippet of the problem:

```
public static function processInput(s:String):String
{
    var result:Null<Float> = parseNumber(s);

    if (result != null)
    {
        return Std.string(result);
    }

    var closeParPos:Int = 0;
    var openParPos:Int = 0;
    var basicOp:String;
    var answer:String = "";

// ERROR HERE
    while (Std.string(answer) != s)
    {
        closeParPos = s.indexOf(")");
        openParPos = s.lastIndexOf("(", closeParPos);

        basicOp = s.substring(openParPos, closeParPos + 1);

        answer = processBasicOp(basicOp);
// This isn't executed
        s.replace(basicOp, answer);

        trace("Input: " + s + " basicOp: " + basicOp + " Answer: " + answer);
    }

    return (result == null)? "": Std.string(result);
}
```

All the code is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35Hl-dotbcXVUpIWTJ2VHgzeW8/view?usp=sharing) just run `make test`

The input syntax is: `([number] [operator] [number])` or `([operator] [number])`
There must be a single space between number and operators.
There shouldn't be any space between numbers and parenthesis

Supported operations:

`+` `-` `/` `*`
`%` (remainder),
`div` (quotient),
`sqr` (square),
`sqroot` (square root),
`sin` `cos` `tan` (in degrees, bugged)
`fact` (factorial)

It isn't completed yet, there may be other problems, but this problem prevents me from advancing.

Can someone help me find the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I created a haxe library for this (https://github.com/markknol/hx-mathparser) but that only supports groups and +, -, / and *. Maybe you can take a look at it.

If you need more advanced haxe parser, you might want to take a look at hscript (https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hscript), which can execute many types of Haxe code.

Comment: @MarkKnol I will check your library when I can, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't actually get this to run, but StringTools.replace() doesn't modify the string in-place.

Try changing `s.replace(basicOp, answer);` to `s = s.replace(basicOp, answer);`